# use fileReader in java to read one character at a time

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, filereader, readline

As a part of a school exercise, I am trying to read characters from a text file and count the frequency of the characters appeared the text file. I stored the frequency in an array, where the index is the ASCII code of the char, and the number in the array is the frequency.

```
   int c;
  FileReader fr = new FileReader (inputFile);
  int [] freq = new int [200];
     while ( (c= fr.read())!= -1){
        int index = c;
        freq [index]= freq [index]+1;
  }
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

  for (int i =0; i<frequency.length; i++) {
      if(frequency[i]!=0){
          pw.println( ((char)i) + " " +frequency[i]);
```

Somehow this method only works with text files with a single line, like "abcdefgh". It doesn't work with files with multiple lines, like "ab /newline cde /newline..." For this type of file, it will generate a blank line and some numbers on top of the result when I print out the array. I really couldn't figure out why.

Comment: For starters, the code isn't syntactically valid. Each statement needs to end with a semicolon, and `c` is undeclared.

Comment: Updated my answer in response to the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine to me.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/tmp/a");
        int[] freq = new int[200];
        int c;
        while ((c = fr.read()) != -1) {
            freq[c] = freq[c] + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(freq));
    }
}
```

Example contents of `/tmp/a`:

```
abc
def
```

Output:

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

**edit** - In response to the revised question:

The output is

`2
    a 1
    b 1
    c 1
    d 1
    e 1
    f 1`

The file has two line breaks, so the program is writing a line break, and then "2".

I'm guessing you want to convert the characters to something like their Java escape sequences. Here's a solution using [Apache commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        write(read());
    }

    static int[] read() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/tmp/a");
        int[] freq = new int[200];
        int c;
        while ((c = fr.read()) != -1) {
            freq[c] = freq[c] + 1;
        }
        return freq;
    }

    static void write(int[] freq) throws IOException {
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("/tmp/b"))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
                if (freq[i] != 0) {
                    char c = (char) i;
                    String s = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("" + c);
                    pw.println(s + " " + freq[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
\n 2
a 1
b 1
c 1
d 1
e 1
f 1
```

Comment: Thanks! but somehow it didn't work for me.. I used a printWriter pw and used a for loop  "pw.println( ((char)i) + " " +frequency[i])"; DO you see any problems with the printWriter? I have added the print writer to the code too